# How do I go about creating a dynamic wheel in React Native?

Tags: react-native

[image: Example]

The wheel shown in the attached picture is completely dynamic (i.e. the user can choose to add or remove categories, and the score for each category can be increased/decreased in a way that changes the color fill percentage of the chosen slice)

I am trying to implement a similar wheel in my React Native app. I implemented one using the native components but it's not nearly as smooth or customizable. Any tips on how I can go about this?

Comment: Check out react-native-svg - dynamically creating the graphic eg with the Circle component. You could take a look at some progress circle libraries for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

may be you can try this package it will be helpfull
https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit